# Finding Solutions to a Set of Equations

Tags: computer-science, graph-theory, breadth-first-search, solver, equations

Suppose I have some known relations between some variables, for example `a = b + c` and a starting solution, e.g. `a=2, b=1, c=1`. I'm writing some code such that, given an update, e.g. `a=3`, I update the values of `b` and `c` so that the relation is still satisfied, e.g. set `b=2` (Clearly there are many possibilities, I just need *one*).

In practice, there are many relations, and they are not linear. The code works via the user providing functions for each variable as a function of the others, for example `a(b,c)` ,`b(a,c)`, and `c(a,b)`. I then build a dependency graph, and when one value is changed, I do something like a breadth-first-search to update the other values. This seems to work, but I can't help but think I'm reinventing the wheel, and this is some very well known computer science / graph theory problem. Perhaps there's even a package?

Could anyone provide some links or some insight into what exactly this problem is I'm solving?

Answer (score 0):

That looks like finding a root of multidimensional function (e.g. `F(a,b,c)=b+c-a`) that is close to given starting point (e.g. `b=1, c=1`.)

[Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm) page describes root finding methods for one variable function and has links to higher dimension methods. These methods are connected to multidimensional optimization problem.

There are many implementations: [SciPy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html), [GNU](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Multidimensional-Root_002dFinding.html), Mathematica, Matlab, ...